# NSNumberFormatter rejecting all changes from user: "the value '3' is invalid"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I am using an NSNumberFormatter, but it doesn't quite work like I expected it.
Everything I type in that field gets reject with the message "the value '[value]' is invalid".
It has the following settings:

```
Behavior: Mac OS X 10.4+ Default
Style: Currency
Localize: YES
Sample: Unformatted: 1234,75 Formatted: € 1.234,75
```

I left the `Constraints` fields empty.
What should I change to turn `3` into `€ 3,00` or at least get it to accept values like `€ 31,56`?

While testing a last time before posting, I somehow managed to get the value `€ 34,12` in there. When trying to edit it, it even rejects my edit if I enter the exact same value with the above message.

While testing a last-last time before posting I noticed that if I choose `discard changes` in the dialog with that nasty error message the value turns from empty into `€ 0,00` and if I press enter it accepts that value. But if I double-click the table cell again and press enter without changing anything it rejects it (although I'm still able to get € 0,00 in it with discard changes)...

**EDIT:**
When in IB I can fill in whatever I want in the `Unformatted` field, and the desired output appears in the `Formatted` field.

Comment: Sounds like the NumberFormatter's Minimum and Maximum Value are activated.

Comment: That would be the _empty_ constraints fields. But I tried values ranging from 0 to ~1500. @DigiMonk